# Link local SQL Express 2005 database to online MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-server-express

I have a software dumping values to a local SQL Express database once a day. What I really need is this data in an online MySQL database. The software cannot be reconfigured to save to a different database setup.

Is there any way of linking the two and having any updates to the local database sent to the MySQL database?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have access to the server the software sits on? I would create a script and a scheduled task that is on the server, and pulls from one and pushes to the other. This would allow you to code and configure some sort of fail safe mechanism should one or the other be down. Otherwise one other option is to add a trigger for the SQL server for inserts/updates, and configure a MySQL DSN:

http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/